# How do I pass AMI tag values in lambda function written in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I have the following Python 3.7 Lambda function and I want to delete AMIs that are older than 90 days but I want to exclude any AMIs that have the tag/value combo of 'amiarchive' / 'yes'. When I run this I get the error "list indices must be integers or slices, not str". I've done a bunch of research and I can't quite figure this out.

````
import collections
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

region ='us-east-1'

aws_account_numbers = {"accountA":"xxxxxxxxxxxx"}

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    delete_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=90)  

   
    for name, acctnum in aws_account_numbers.items():
        roleArn = "arn:aws:iam::%s:role/EOTSS-Snapshot-Cleanup-90days" % acctnum
        stsClient = boto3.client('sts')
        sts_response = stsClient.assume_role(RoleArn=roleArn,RoleSessionName='AssumeCrossAccountRole', DurationSeconds=1800)
        ec2 = boto3.resource(service_name='ec2',region_name=region,aws_access_key_id = sts_response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
                aws_secret_access_key = sts_response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'], aws_session_token = sts_response['Credentials']['SessionToken'])
                
        ec = boto3.client('ec2', 'us-east-1')
        images = ec2.images.filter(Owners=["self"])
        tag=[{"Name" :"tag:amiarchive", "Values":[] }]
        
        for image in images:  

                t = datetime.strptime(image.creation_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
                
                try:
                    if delete_time > t and (tag['Value']) != yes:
                        print ("AMI %s deregistered in acct: %s" % (image.image_id, acctnum))
                        response = image.deregister()
                                
                except ClientError as e:
                    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidImage.InUse':
                        print("Image in use")
                        continue
                    else:
                        print("Unexpected error: %s" % e)
                        continue
                        
    return 'Execution Complete'```
````

Answer (score 1):

You declare

```
tag=[{"Name" :"tag:amiarchive", "Values":[] }]
```

So `tag` is a list (array) that contains one item (which is an object).  You need to use an integer index to access this, such as tag[0].  Then, once you have the object at tag[0] you can get its properties such as `Name` and `Values`.  Your code calls `tag['Value']` and that creates the error you see.

Comment: Thank you Shawn. I ended up re-working the code a bit with the help of a co-worker.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up re-working the code with a co-worker. I changed to boto3.client rather than using boto3.client and added an additional for loop to check for the existence of the tag / value combination and skip the remaining steps if that condition is true. The following code does the trick.

```
import collections
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

region ='us-east-1'

aws_account_numbers = {"AccountA":"xxxxxxxxxxxx"}

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    delete_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=67)  

   
    for name, acctnum in aws_account_numbers.items():
        roleArn = "arn:aws:iam::%s:role/EOTSS-Snapshot-Cleanup-90days" % acctnum
        stsClient = boto3.client('sts')
        sts_response = stsClient.assume_role(RoleArn=roleArn,RoleSessionName='AssumeCrossAccountRole', DurationSeconds=1800)
        ec2 = boto3.client(service_name='ec2',region_name=region,aws_access_key_id = sts_response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
            aws_secret_access_key = sts_response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'], aws_session_token = sts_response['Credentials']['SessionToken'])
        
        ec = boto3.client('ec2', 'us-east-1')
        images2 = ec2.describe_images(Owners=['self'])      

        for image in images2['Images']:
            if 'Tags' in image:
                for tag in image['Tags']:
                    if tag['Key'] == 'amiarchive' and tag['Value'] == 'yes':
                        print("Skipping Image",image['ImageId'],"because its archived")
                        continue

                t = datetime.strptime(image['CreationDate'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")

                try:
                    if delete_time > t:
                        print ("AMI %s deregistered in acct: %s" % (image['ImageId'], acctnum))
                        #response = image.deregister()
                                
                except ClientError as e:
                    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidImage.InUse':
                        print("Image in use")
                        continue
                    else:
                        print("Unexpected error: %s" % e)
                        continue
                        
    return 'Execution Complete''''
```